# Change shipping method rate value font weight in WooCommerce cart page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

How do I remove the bold font from the shipping fees in WooCommerce cart page? I don't want to call too much attention to the shipping fee with the bold text, so I want to have regular font weight there.

Note that I renamed "Shipping" to "Delivery" below
[image]

**Update:**
Adding the html code below in response to question in comment section

```
<tr class="woocommerce-shipping-totals shipping">
<th>Delivery</th>
<td data-title="Delivery">
    <ul id="ship_method" class="woocommerce-ship-type">
        <li> 
        class="ship_method"/><label for="ship_method"> <span class="woocommerce_totals totals"><span class="woocommerce_curr_sym">&#36;</span>300.00</span></label>                 </li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

Comment: See above in main question for the html code.

Comment: Your edited the generated html in wrong way, see: `<li>   class="ship_method"/>` … I have updated my answer too.

Comment: Did it, Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit based on your question 2nd Edit** *(where you changed the generated html output)*

You can use the following CCS rule to be added in your theme's `styles.css` file *(for cart)*:

```css
.cart-collaterals #ship_method label,
.cart-collaterals #ship_method label span {
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

For cart **and checkout** pages use:

```css
#ship_method label,
#ship_method label span {
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

It should work.

---

**Original answer** *(works for Woocommerce default html structure)*

You can use the following CCS rule to be added in your theme's `styles.css` file *(for cart)*:

```css
.cart-collaterals #shipping_method label,
.cart-collaterals #shipping_method label span {
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

For cart **and checkout** pages use:

```css
#shipping_method label,
#shipping_method label span {
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

It should work.

Answer (score 2):

Just inspect the shipping fee value and take the class of the shipping fee value. For example, the class name is: **.shipping_fee**. So just put the following css in your Additional CSS or your Custom CSS file.

```
.shipping_fee {
 font-weight: normal !important;
}
```